# Constructing a transformation satisfying the given properties

Tags: real-analysis

Construct a transformation which maps the plane into the plane itself , and the curve $y=x^2$ onto the horizontal axis, and the line $y=3$ onto the vertical axis.

I need to solve the set of equations $$T(x,x^2) = (x,0) \\ T(x,3)= (0,y) $$ but couldn't. Any hints?

Comment: $T(x,y) = (0,0)$ works I guess

Comment: The points $(\pm\sqrt{3}, 3)$ would need to be mapped to $(0,0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the transformation be $f(x,y) = (f_1(x,y), f_2(x,y))$.

The line $y = 3$ is mapped to $x = 0$ so $f_1(x,3) = 0$ for all $x$. This means that we can set $f_1(x,y) = M_1(y-3)$ for a some constant $M_1$. Similarly, we can set $f_2(x,y) = M_2(x^2 - y)$.

Then we have $f(x,y) = (M_1(y-3), M_2(x^2 - y))$.